# Http response in android

Tags: android, http, https

I am developing an application where I need to call a webservice on button click in android.

```
HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
httpConn.connect();
response = httpConn.getResponseCode();
```

the pesponse code which I am getting is -1 first time and then it gives me  the 200 requestcode which is for ok. What is the problem (I am using https urls).

Answer (score 0):

You have to implements SocketFactory, LayeredSocketFactory class and manage the socket and also implement X509TrustManager.

Check This Link
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Network/FakeSocketFactory.htm.

Comment: what? What is that craziness. He just wants to make a GET request for god's sake…

Comment: its getting the response sometimes.. idont think i need what @Bhargav Panchal mentioned...

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion Try to Use AsyncHttpclient for getting responses from server no need of this long codes.

http://loopj.com/android-async-http/

```
 AsyncHttpClient asyncHttpClient=new AsyncHttpClient();

            asyncHttpClient.get("http://10.0.2.2/fanaticmobile/log_in.php", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler(){
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable arg0, String arg1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.onFailure(arg0, arg1);
                }
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.onSuccess(arg0);
                }
            });
```

Just include the jar file in your project it will be simple to use.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to wait more for a connection to get established, so set a timeout for a connection:

```
httpConn.setConnectTimeout(10000);
httpConn.setReadTimeout(10000);
```